# How to get a nextLine in the txt file after user inputs string?

Tags: java, file-io

Just started coding and found my self overwhelmed with different types of writing to a file. I'm using File and PrintStream library. My issue is that after user is done with typing notes and reopens the file, the file is overwritten. I wish to add just a nextLine function so when the file is opened again we just add text to line2.  Thank you in advance.

This is my piece of code:

```
if(userOption.equals("open") || userOption.equals("OPEN") ){
        System.out.print("Please enter the name of the file you want to open : ");
        fileNameOpen = kybd.nextLine();
        File input = new File( fileNameOpen );
        PrintStream  print = new PrintStream( input );
        System.out.print("Now you can start typing your notes: ");
       // print.println(userNotes = kybd.nextLine());
        print.println(userNotes = kybd.nextLine());
        print.close();

    }//end of if
```

Comment: I hope the below link answers your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401385/how-to-append-new-data-to-existing-data-in-properties-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want something simple, this will work:

```
try {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileNameOpen , true)));
    userNotes = kybd.nextLine()
    out.println(userNotes);
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    //oh noes!
}
```

The second parameter to the FileWriter constructor will tell it to append to the file (as opposed to clearing the file).

Of course you will need to incorporate this into your logic.

Comment: so I don't need that PrintStream?

Comment: worked like a charm... thank you...now how do I make it so its not just a line of text but till user let say do something, i don't know like x or -1 to finish typing. Would I use i.e while(userNotes != -1) ???

Comment: the userNotes is going to be a String, so use String methods e.g. `userNotes.equals("-1)`.  test for this immediately after input and if it is true, then break your loop.

Comment: while(!userNotes.equals(" -1")){
          
          userNotes = kybd.nextLine();
       out.println(userNotes);
         }
        
         out.close();   
     
     }

Answer (score 0):

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                  new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileNameOpen, true)));
```

The second argument in the `FileWriter` will allow you to append a line

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(userOption.equals("open") || userOption.equals("OPEN") ){
    System.out.print("Please enter the name of the file you want to open : ");
    Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileNameOpen = kybd.next();
    kybd.nextLine();

    try{
         String data = " This content will append to the end of the file";

         File file = new File(fileNameOpen);

         // if file does not exist create it
         if(!file.exists()){
             file.createNewFile();
         }

         //true = append file
         FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);
         BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
         writer.write(data);
         writer.close();

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}//end of if
```